# windows - monitoring cpu/net/io with history

Tags: windows

Is there any free/opensource software for windows (desktop) which will save historical cpu/net/io usage and let me see charts based on this historical data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are two ways you could do this.

Your first way is to use tools built into windows already.  Just go to Start > Run and enter

> perfmon

Performance Monitor should open up and you can follow this link to learn how to create a log:

[Click Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150934)

The other tool you could use which is free/opensource is nagios which relies on snmp data.  Make sure to go to Start > Run and enter

> services.msc

And make sure SNMP trap service is running.  Make sure to also configure your snmp community string to something other than "public"

For information on setting up snmp on your Windows box you can follow this link:

[Click Here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/01/install-and-enable-snmp-service-in-windows-xp-vista-and-2003/)

Performance monitor built into Windows is by far easier to use and will likely have all the data that you require.  Nagios is far more extensive but is also a bit more to do config-wise.

Comment: Just to clarify a point. Nagios is not based on SNMP even though it can be configured to use SNMP.

Comment: Sorry but I've forgotten that this question is related to Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

Enabling SNMP and collecting with MRTG or any of its RRDTool-based successors. Of course, Performance Monitor (built into the OS) will do it too.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out nagios. This is a terrific tool that can handle what you need plus quite a bit. It does require some time but once it is up and running it is rock solid.